# Cannot get my placement of labels right in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I am trying to build a gui that uses gridbaglayout, so I can place labels and buttons at specific positions. Currently this is what my program gives me:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2dmcj0n.jpg]

This is what I am aiming to get:
[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/fu5lig.jpg]

Basically, I want to move the logout button to the southeast corner and the picture more towards the left and the labels a little towards right. I have tried changing the gridx and gridy of the picture and the labels but the picture doesn't move any more left and I move the labels a little to the right, the picture moves to the right as well. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Library{
    private static JFrame frame;
    private GridBagConstraints padding;
    private JLabel addB;
    private JTextField aB;
    private JLabel issueB;
    private JTextField iB;
    private JLabel holdB;
    private JTextField hB;
    private JLabel renewB;
    private JTextField rB;
    private JButton logout;
    private ImageIcon logo;

    public Library(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }



    //deals with the adding of textfield and label of adding book
    private void addBLabels()
    {
        addB = new JLabel("Add Book: ");
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(addB, padding);
        padding.gridwidth = 30;
        aB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(aB, padding);
    }

    //deals with issue book labels
    private void issueBLabels(){
        issueB = new JLabel("Issue Book: ");
        padding.gridwidth = 1;
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(issueB, padding);
        padding.gridwidth = 30;
        iB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(iB, padding);
    }

    //deals with holdbook labels
    private void holdBookLabels(){
        holdB = new JLabel("Hold Book: ");
        padding.gridwidth = 1;
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 2;
        frame.add(holdB, padding);
        hB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.gridwidth = 30;
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 2;
        frame.add(hB, padding);
    }

    //deals with the renewbook labels
    private void renewBookLabels(){
        renewB = new JLabel("Renew Book: ");
        padding.gridwidth = 1;
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 3;
        frame.add(renewB, padding);
        rB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.gridwidth = 30;
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 3;
        frame.add(rB, padding);
    }

    //deals with adding the logout button
    private void logOutButton(){
        logout = new JButton("Logout");
        padding.gridwidth = 1;
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 5;
        frame.add(logout, padding);
    }

    //deals with adding the image
    private void addImage() throws IOException{
        InputStream imageStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("0521-1005-0822-0024_brunette_girl_smiling_and_holding_a_stack_books.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        padding.gridx = 0;
        padding.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(picLabel, padding);
        frame.pack();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Library gui = new Library();
        gui.addBLabels();
        gui.issueBLabels();
        gui.holdBookLabels();
        gui.renewBookLabels();
        gui.logOutButton();
        gui.addImage();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(1000,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` requires much more than just x and y coordinates specified to do what it does best. You really should read and understand the [How To Use GridBagLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) before proceeding. As the tutorial itself declares, *"GridBagLayout is one of the most flexible — and complex — layout managers the Java platform provides."*

Don't use the same instance of `GridBagConstraints` for your components - that might lead to problems. At least one such instance should specify the `weightx`and `weighty` values, otherwise your components are going to be clumped together in the center of the container. Use `gridwidth` and `gridheight` to specify how many columns/rows your component will occupy (for example your picture should span across all your labels). Use `Insets` to define how much space should be left around your components. Use `anchor` to place components within their cells.

Here's an example (did not really understand what you wanted to do, but it should get you started - if you read the tutorial):

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Library {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private JLabel addB;
    private JTextField aB;
    private JLabel issueB;
    private JTextField iB;
    private JLabel holdB;
    private JTextField hB;
    private JLabel renewB;
    private JTextField rB;
    private JButton logout;
    private ImageIcon logo;

    public Library() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    //deals with the adding of textfield and label of adding book
    private void addBLabels() {
        addB = new JLabel("Add Book: ");
        GridBagConstraints padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(addB, padding);
        padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        aB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(aB, padding);
    }

    //deals with issue book labels
    private void issueBLabels() {
        issueB = new JLabel("Issue Book: ");
        GridBagConstraints padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(issueB, padding);
        padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        iB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(iB, padding);
    }

    //deals with holdbook labels
    private void holdBookLabels() {
        holdB = new JLabel("Hold Book: ");
        GridBagConstraints padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 2;
        frame.add(holdB, padding);
        padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        hB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 2;
        frame.add(hB, padding);
    }

    //deals with the renewbook labels
    private void renewBookLabels() {
        renewB = new JLabel("Renew Book: ");
        GridBagConstraints padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 4;
        padding.gridy = 3;
        frame.add(renewB, padding);
        padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        rB = new JTextField(30);
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 3;
        frame.add(rB, padding);
    }

    //deals with adding the logout button
    private void logOutButton() {
        logout = new JButton("Logout");
        GridBagConstraints padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        padding.gridx = 5;
        padding.gridy = 5;
        padding.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
        padding.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
        frame.add(logout, padding);
    }

    //deals with adding the image
    private void addImage() throws IOException {
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
        GridBagConstraints padding = new GridBagConstraints();
        padding.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        padding.gridx = 0;
        padding.gridy = 0;
        padding.weighty = 1.0d;
        padding.weightx = 1.0d;
        padding.gridheight = 6;
        padding.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        padding.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        frame.add(picLabel, padding);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Library gui = new Library();
                gui.addBLabels();
                gui.issueBLabels();
                gui.holdBookLabels();
                gui.renewBookLabels();
                gui.logOutButton();
                try {
                    gui.addImage();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```